# How to show scroll text in Corona sdk

Tags: text, scroll, show, coronasdk

I need to show a text that is most large that the height simulator screen. My text is showed throw:

local detailScreenTextDescripcion = display.newText("Descripcion", 0, 0, (display.contentWidth*2) ,0 , native.systemFont, 12)

The large is not limited on a visible field because his value is 0, I don't know how can I see  the rest of the text what disappears at the bottom of the screen.

THANKS

Comment: The only way to measure that is to measure string and calculate, if it will fill the screen or not. Then you can change font or scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that will scroll/move your text from right to left.
And you can add some functionality to it. Ex: onTextClick "resume scrolling"/"stop scrolling".

```
local function scrollText(text)
    transition.to( text, { time=3000, alpha=0, x=-(textWidth - display.contentWidth),} )
end
```